# How to render d3 graph ticks above shaded region or graph itself?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I want ticks to come above shaded region in graph, i have tried transparency but it will not work.

Due to some constraint i cannot change the way i am coloring green region, but its like this-> Shade area below above line with green, then area below bottom line as white(same as chart background color)

Now due to this, ticks are hiding behind, is there a way i can place them above? or redraw new ticks in shaded region?

[Click here for image of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3lDT.png)

```js
renderGraph: function(){
  // Data notice the structure
  //************************************************************
  var data =  [
   [{'x':1,'y':7},{'x':2,'y':7},{'x':3,'y':7},{'x':4,'y':7},{'x':4.5,'y':8.1},{'x':6.3,'y':8.1},{'x':6.8,'y':7},{'x':8,'y':7},{'x':9,'y':8},{'x':10,'y':8}],
   [{'x':1,'y':9},{'x':2,'y':8},{'x':3,'y':11},{'x':4,'y':10},{'x':5,'y':10},{'x':6,'y':9},{'x':7,'y':10},{'x':8,'y':10},{'x':9,'y':11},{'x':10,'y':10}],
   [{'x':1,'y':9.5},{'x':2,'y':9},{'x':3,'y':10.5},{'x':4,'y':9},{'x':5,'y':10},{'x':6,'y':9},{'x':7,'y':11},{'x':8,'y':10},{'x':9,'y':11},{'x':10,'y':11}],
   [{'x':1,'y':8},{'x':2,'y':8},{'x':3,'y':8},{'x':4,'y':8},{'x':5,'y':10},{'x':6,'y':10},{'x':7,'y':8},{'x':8,'y':8},{'x':9,'y':9},{'x':10,'y':9}],
   [{'x':1,'y':10},{'x':2,'y':10},{'x':3,'y':10},{'x':4,'y':11},{'x':5,'y':11},{'x':6.5,'y':11},{'x':7,'y':10},{'x':8,'y':10},{'x':9,'y':11},{'x':10,'y':11}]
  ];
  
  var dataAboveLine = [{'x':1,'y':10},{'x':2,'y':10},{'x':3,'y':10},{'x':4,'y':11},{'x':5,'y':11},{'x':6.5,'y':11},{'x':7,'y':10},{'x':8,'y':10},{'x':9,'y':11},{'x':10,'y':11}];
  var dataBelowLine = [{'x':1,'y':7},{'x':2,'y':7},{'x':3,'y':7},{'x':4,'y':7},{'x':4.5,'y':8.1},{'x':6.3,'y':8.1},{'x':6.8,'y':7},{'x':8,'y':7},{'x':9,'y':8},{'x':10,'y':8}];
  
  var colors = [
   'steelblue',
   'RGB(0,93,135)',
   'RGB(226,0,26)',
   'RGB(142,166,78)'
  ]
  
  var lineType = [
       '0 1', //5 0
       '5 0',
       '5 0',
       '8 5'
   ]
   

  //************************************************************
  // Create Margins and Axis and hook our zoom function
  //************************************************************
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
   
  var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 12])
      .range([0, width]);
   
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([-1, 16])
      .range([height, 0]);
   
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
   //.tickSize(-height)
   .tickPadding(10) 
   .tickSubdivide(true) 
      .orient("bottom"); 
   
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
   .tickPadding(10)
   .tickSize(-width)
   .tickSubdivide(true) 
      .orient("left");
   
  var area = d3.svg.area()
     .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
     .y0(height)
     .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
  
  
  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(x)
      .y(y)
      .scaleExtent([1, 3])
      .on("zoom", zoomed); 
   
   var vertical = d3.select("#chartHolder")
         .append("div")
         .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
         .attr("class", "remove")
         .style("position", "absolute")
         .style("z-index", "19")
         .style("width", "1px")
         .style("height", "450px")
        // .style("top", "39px")
         .style("top", "46px")
         .style("bottom", "1px")
         .style("left", "8px")
         .style("background", "#000");
   
   var horizontal = d3.select("#chartHolder")
         .append("div")
         .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
         .attr("class", "remove")
         .style("position", "absolute")
         .style("z-index", "19")
         .style("width", "881px")
         .style("height", "1px")
         .style("top", "47px")
         .style("bottom", "1px")
         .style("left", "57px")
         .style("background", "#000");
   
  //************************************************************
  // Generate our SVG object
  //************************************************************ 
  var svg = d3.select("#chartHolder").append("svg")
   .call(zoom)
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("class", "svgClass")
   .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
   
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
   
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
  
//   svg.append("g")
//   .attr("class", "x axis")
//   .append("text")
//   .attr("class", "axis-label")
//   .attr("y", 500)
//   .attr("x", 400)
//   .text('new'); 
   
  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .append("text")
   .attr("class", "axis-label")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
   .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 10)
   .attr("x", -height/2)
   .text('Hours'); 
   
  svg.append("clipPath")
   .attr("id", "clip")
   .append("rect")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);
   
  
  svg.append("path")
     .datum(dataAboveLine)
     .attr("class", "areaAbove")
     .attr("d", area)
     .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  
  
  svg.append("path")
     .datum(dataBelowLine)
     .attr("class", "areaBelow")
     .attr("d", area)
     .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  
   
  //************************************************************
  // Create D3 line object and draw data on our SVG object
  //************************************************************
  var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("linear") 
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });  
   
  svg.selectAll('.line')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
   .attr('stroke', function(d,i){    
    return colors[i%colors.length];
   })
   .style("stroke-dasharray", function(d,i){
    return lineType[i%lineType.length]; 
   })
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("stroke-width","3px");  
   
  
  // Define the div for the tooltip
  var div = d3.select("#chartHolder").append("div") 
      .attr("class", "tooltip")    
      .style("opacity", 0);
   
  //************************************************************
  // Draw points on SVG object based on the data given
  //************************************************************
  var points = svg.selectAll('.dots')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
      .attr("class", "dots")
   .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)"); 
   
  points.selectAll('.dot')
   .data(function(d, index){   
    var a = [];
    d.forEach(function(point,i){
     a.push({'index': index, 'point': point});
    });  
    return a;
   })
   .enter()
   .append('circle')
   .on("click", function(d){click(d)})
   .attr('class','dot')
   .attr("r", 3.5)
   .attr('fill', function(d,i){  
    return colors[d.index%colors.length];
   }) 
   .attr('fill-opacity', function(d,i){
    if(d.index==0||d.index==4||d.index==3){
     return '0';
    }
   })
   .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
   )
   .on("mouseover", function(d) {  
         div.transition()  
            // .duration(200)  
             .style("opacity", .9);  
         div .html("X:"+d.point.x + "<br/>"  +"Y:"+ d.point.y) 
             .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")  
             .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
         })     
         .on("mouseout", function(d) {  
             div.transition()  
                // .duration(500)  
                 .style("opacity", 0); 
         });
   
   
   function click(d){
    alert(JSON.stringify(d.point));
   }
   
   
   
  //************************************************************
  // Zoom specific updates
  //************************************************************
  function zoomed() {
   svg.select(".areaAbove").call(area);
   
   svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
   svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);  
   
   svg.selectAll('path.line').attr('d', line);  
   
   svg.select('.areaAbove').attr('d', area);
   svg.select('.areaBelow').attr('d', area);
   
   points.selectAll('circle').attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
   );  
  }
  var txtCycle = d3.select("#chartHolder").append("p")
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "yaxis-label")
  .attr("y", 463)
  .attr("x", 400)
  .text('Number of cycles');
  
  var slider = d3.select("#chartHolder").append("p").append("input")
    .datum({})
    .attr("type", "range")
    .attr("class","slider")
    .attr("value", zoom.scaleExtent()[0])
    .attr("min", zoom.scaleExtent()[0])
    .attr("max", zoom.scaleExtent()[1])
    .attr("step", (zoom.scaleExtent()[1] - zoom.scaleExtent()[0]) / 100)
    .on("input", slided);
  


  var svgimg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'height','22');
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'width','350');
  svgimg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href', 'xaxis.PNG');
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'x','580');
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'y','450');
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');
  
  $('svg').append(svgimg);
  function slided(d){
     zoom.scale(d3.select(this).property("value"))
       .event(svg);
   }
      

  
 //for crosshairs
   d3.select("#chartHolder")
       .on("mousemove", function(){  
          coord = d3.mouse(this);
          mousex = coord[0];
          mousey=coord[1];
//           vertical.style("left", mousex+ "px" );
//           horizontal.style("top", mousey +"px")
          if((mousex+6)>935){
           mousex=929;
          }
          if((mousex+6)<59){
           mousex=53;
          }
          if((mousey+6)>495){
           mousey=489;
          }
          if((mousey+6)<44){
           mousey=39;
          }
          vertical.style("left", mousex+6+ "px" );
          horizontal.style("top", mousey+6 +"px");
       })
   
       .on("mouseover", function(){  
        coord = d3.mouse(this);
          mousex = coord[0];
          mousey=coord[1];
          if((mousex+6)>930){
           mousex=924;
          }
          if((mousex+6)<51){
           mousex=45;
          }
          if((mousey+6)<39){
           mousey=33;
          }
          if((mousey+6)>487){
           mousey=481;
          }
//           vertical.style("left", mousex + "px");
//           horizontal.style("top", mousey +"px")});
   
          vertical.style("left", mousex +6+ "px");
          horizontal.style("top", mousey +6+"px")});

  // add cross hairs and floating value on axis
  /*
  var chart = d3.select("svg");
  
  var focusText = chart.append("g")
  .attr("class","focus")
  .style("display", "none");

     focusText.append("text").attr({"x": 9, "dy": "0.35em"});
     
     
  var focus = chart.append("g")
   .attr("class","focus")
   .style("display", "none");

      //focus.append("text").attr({"x": 9, "dy": "0.35em"});
     
      // horizontal crosshair 
      focus.append("line")
            .attr({
              "x1": -width,
              "y1": 0,
              "x2": width,
              "y2": 0
            });


      // vertical crosshair
      
      focus.append("line")
              .attr({
                "x1": 0,
                "y1": -height,
                "x2": 0,
                "y2": height
              });
      
      
      chart.append("rect")
          .attr({"class": "overlay" , "width": width , "height": height})
          .on({
            "mouseover": function() { focus.style("display", null);   focusText.style("display", null); },
            "mouseout":  function() { focus.style("display", "none"); focusText.style("display", "none"); }, 
            "mousemove": mousemove
          });
    


  function mousemove() {
   var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
          i = bisectDate(sample2, x0, 1),
          d0 = sample2[i-1],
          d1 = sample2[i],
          d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    
   focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + (d3.mouse(this)[0]) + "," + yScale(d.close) + ")");
      focusText.attr("transform", "translate(" + (width-margin.right) + "," + yScale(d.close) + ")");
      focusText.select("text").text("$" + d.close);

  } */
 //
 } 

renderGraph();
```

```css
.sapUiBody{
    background-color: white;
    background-image: none;
}

.grid .tick {
 stroke: lightgrey;
 opacity: 0.7;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
.grid path {
 stroke-width: 0;
}
 
.axis path {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #bbb;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
.axis text {
 fill: #555;
}
 
.axis line { 
 stroke: #e7e7e7;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
.axis .axis-label {
 font-size: 14px;
}
 .yaxis-label{
 left: 448px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
 }
 
.line {
 fill: none;
 stroke-width: 2.0px;
}
 
.dot {
 /* consider the stroke-with the mouse detect radius? */
 stroke: transparent;
 stroke-width: 10px;  
 cursor: pointer;
}
 div.tooltip { 
    position: absolute;   
    text-align: center;   
    width: 60px;     
    height: 28px;     
    padding: 2px;    
    font: 12px sans-serif;  
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;  
    border-radius: 8px;   
    pointer-events: none;   
}
.areaBelow {
    fill: white;
    stroke-width: 0;
}

.areaAbove {
  fill: RGB(142,166,78);
    stroke-width: 0;
        opacity: 0.34;
}

.dot:hover {
 stroke: rgba(68, 127, 255, 0.3);
}
 
.slider{
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
  <div id="content"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just change the order of the drawing parts in your code. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2537/core-svg-concepts-used-in-d3-js-visualization/18029/svg-the-drawing-order#t=20160824062912133062 If, by any chance, you are using D3 v4.x, a simple raise() would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but i am using v3 and version change would be last option for me. Any other option?

Comment: As I wrote above, just change the order in your code. Anything that's painted last is on top.